# Do I have to have textField.delegate=self for every textField Input in my ViewController

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am doing a Sign In form and I want to delegate some of the textField functions with my LoginViewController.
So my question is should I have textField.delegate=self for every text field in my Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your requirement. If you need to perform some task upon selection/editing of every textfield then yes you need to set the delegate of all the textfields. But if you don't then set the delegate of only those that are required.

If you set the delegate of multiple textfields, you also need to add a check in delegate methods to know which textfield has fired the delegate.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there could be a sort of "generic" way, but there isn't